# Change document root via .htaccess issue

Tags: php, .htaccess

When I echo out the document root I get this: `/etc/httpd/htdocs`

however I get the error, when I try to run my website:

> No such file or directory in
>   /vhost/vhost14/i/n/d/domainname.co.uk/www/testme.php

on this line of code

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/_cmsscripts/_init.php");
```

if I replace the `$_SERVER` with `/vhost/vhost14/i/n/d/domainname.co.uk/www/` it all works, but I've got loads of pages and don't really want to have to go around and change the whole site.  First time I've had this issue and not sure how to get around it.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the document root is not where your current  website in vhost is configured to or `follow_symlinks` is not enabled.

Anyway, in order to find things below the current file, you may use:

```
require_once(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])."/_cmsscripts/_init.php");
```

Obviously, the document root can not be changed by `.htaccess` for security reasons

Comment: Gave that a try and didn't make any difference :(